# How does react-native handle httpOnly cookies for jwt authentication?

Tags: react-native, cookies, jwt

Most authentication providers that use jwt based authentication usually send 2 types of tokens: `jwt` and `refreshToken`. We can store `jwt` in AsyncStorage or even beter SecureStorage modules, but `refreshToken` is normally sent as an httpOnly cookie, so js has no access to it.

How does react-native handle this `httpOnly` cookie? Is there anything we as devs need to do, or will it use it by default when communicating with api that set it?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice today is to not store tokens at all in the browser and instead you should consider the **BFF pattern** as discussed in these two videos:

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=1673s)
- [Using the BFF pattern to secure SPA and Blazor Applications - Dominick Baier - NDC Oslo 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc)

Comment: Looks like this approach relies on same site cookies. How would this work within scope of react-native, as it is not served on domain.

Comment: if you use HTTPS and set it with samesite=none, then there is no problem with cross domain. In what environment do you intend to run your application? For openID-connect do rely on cookies and browser redirects.

Comment: Also, your app is always supposed to open the login page to the authentication service, in a browser window, you never ask your users for their username/password in your app.